# Symbol 'type akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow' is missing from the classpath

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I'm learning Scala and following this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yU85EowqhY4
But when I tried to run my AkkaHttpJson class I end up getting this error

`` Symbol 'type akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow' is missing from the classpath. This symbol is required by 'method akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteResult.routeToFlow'. Make sure that type Flow is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies with `-Ylog-classpath`. A full rebuild may help if 'RouteResult.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of akka.stream.scaladsl. Http().newServerAt("localhost", 8081).bind(route) ``

Why am I getting this error? Everything is exactly as shown in the video.
Is it the dependencies that are causing these issues?
Also, If I make a project using Scala 2.* and then want to convert to Scala 3, would I always face issues?

I'm really new to Scala, so I appreciate all help!

Comment: How are you running your code?

Comment: I'm running `sbt run` if that's what you are asking. i'm also using IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.3 (Ultimate Edition)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this error is raising but as a workaround adding `akka-stream` to the build file's dependency section does the job. No other action were required in my case. So the minimum required dependencies for an Akka-HTTP project as simple as hello world responding to a single route GET request becomes:

```
 libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http"                % akkaHttpVersion,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor-typed"         % akkaVersion,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream"              % akkaVersion
 )
```

Tested with Scala 3.2.2 and perfectly works.

Answer (score -1):

Posted the question [here](https://users.scala-lang.org/t/symbol-type-akka-stream-scaladsl-flow-is-missing-from-the-classpath/9102) and got the answer :)

Comment: Please add a summary of the solution — link-only answers are discouraged (more info: [link-only-answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) and [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer))